# C# .NET dynamic how to get a dynamic obj from enum

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I'm wondering how to get dynamic obj from enum in my case:

For ex. I have some list of objects and I was iterating smth like this:

```
foreach(var case in Viewbag.Cases)
{
   <tr>
        <td>@case.Positive</td>
        <td>@case.Negative</td>
   </tr>
}
```

but I would use my enum where I have:

```
public enum ResultsEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "POSITIVE")]
    Positive = 1,

    [Display(Name = "NEGATIVE")]
    Negative
}
```

in that way:

```
foreach(var case in Viewbag.Cases)
{
   foreach(var enumName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ResultsEnum))
   <tr>
        <td>@case.Positive.@enumName</td>
        <td>@case.Negative.@enumName</td>
   </tr>
}
```

but after that the obj is not dynamic and here is my question:

is it possible to do iteration in that way?

Now my result isn't a record from DB but string case.Negative

Comment: Struggling to understand, please provide structure of `Case` class.

Comment: "but after that the obj is not dynamic" What did you mean here? You just need to provide another type. Something like `Enum.GetNames(GetMyType(...))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to access the `enum` values and then map them to properties in your case objects.

```
foreach (var caseObj in ViewBag.Cases)
{
    <tr>
        @foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ResultsEnum)))
        {
            var enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(ResultsEnum), enumValue);
            var propertyInfo = caseObj.GetType().GetProperty(enumName);
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(caseObj);

            <td>@value</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```